# Image-rendering value gets updated sometimes and sometimes not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got an logo on my page which is big first, but when you scroll down it becomes a small header logo. I did that with a .tiny class which gets toggled on scroll.

```
$(window).on("scroll touchmove", function() {
  $('#logo').toggleClass('tiny', $(document).scrollTop() > 0);
});
```

with the CSS:

```
#logo {
    width: 50%;
    left: 20vw;
    transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}

#logo.tiny {
    width: 230px;
    image-rendering:auto;
}
```

The thing is when the logo gets small the `image-rendering:auto;` gets updated sometimes and sometimes just not. It seems pretty random to me. You can clearly see the difference when `image-rendering:auto;` is active and when it's not. I am testing it in chrome.
Thats my website: http://www.lars-widmer.tk/sites/18/ Just confirm that slide at the beginning (nothing dangerous happens ;) ) and you get to the logo.
Just scroll up and down a few times and you can see that sometimes it looks good and sometimes not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tryout this one :

```
#logo.tiny {
    width: 230px;
    transform: scale(1);
    zoom: 0;
}
```